# Do first impressions really count?

Tags: website-design, marketing

So, i am currently writing something up for a college class. Problem is everything is hypothetical. I need some proof. I believe a first impression on a website is imperative so that people actually use it and in my case, buy your product or services as well.

Basically I'm wondering has there been any studies that shows how a better web design will increase revenue for any kind of services? I don't just mean selling products like a T-shirt, but labor services as well.

If someone wanted their computer fixed and searched for companies that can do so, will a first impression on the website help them make their decision to use your company? Are there any studies like this? White papers maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: I know of this: http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/blink/

Comment: @Adam Thompson - yea i actually saw that too. Probably just have to use those sources that were cited. Its just that the article is so old.

Comment: There's this too, but unfortunately the article isn't free from this source, but you may be able to find it if you look around: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6VC8-4NGBB9X-1&_user=10&_coverDate=01/31/2008&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=gateway&_origin=gateway&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1675997434&_rerunOrigin=scholar.google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=18796966aa5c27479bb91d136d7e9c35&searchtype=a

Comment: @Adam Thompson - can you put that in an answer. That helps me a lot. I wasn't really sure how to search for it, never thought of searching for the credibility of a website. Once you put it in a form of an answer, ill accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think something like this is going to change in a period of 5 years. If web users responded to good web design in 2006, then they're just as likely to respond to good web design in 2016. In any case, both that first page and the research paper in the second link are from 2006.

Comment: IMHO I think you'll have a hard time proving this based on your approach. First you'd need to decide upon your target market. Do you want something instantly entertaining and interactive, a minimalist listing system with clear yet not overstated brand identification, an effective sales "wizard", etc? The most useful studies I've read in this area try to better certain patterns such as the above. First impressions based on well founded disciplines and/or common sense generally succeed. But if some didn't buck the trend there would be no such things as innovation and niché markets/appeal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of common sense. Its basic human trait that man build their attitude to something/someone in the first interaction they have. There are several factors that lead to this so-called first impression. It's not always look. Its sometime a complex combination of the user experience in interacting with the site or the content itself. For a person who looking for information, what is more important is not design or look, but information itself.

Some of the areas that can help in getting good impression are:

1. User Experience.
2. Accessibility
3. Usability.
4. Design
5. Speed.
6. Content Worthiness

**See also:**

- [21 things that influence in first
  impression - Vandelay Design](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/design/first-impression/)
- [First Impression through design -
  UIE](http://www.uie.com/articles/communicate_quick/)
- [A study published in BBC](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/technology/4616700.stm)
- [First Impression Count](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/blink/)

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different take on the first impressions. In the UK there have been quite a few stories of "fake" websites selling products/services which are either of incredibly poor quality or don't sell you anything at all.

The royal wedding later this month and 2012 Olympics means the stories are beginning to crop up again.

To bring this round to your question directly, the media in the UK say a few things with regards to first impressions and a site legitimacy - things like a UK based telephone number clearly displayed, a contact address. https being used when inputting credit card details etc.

I think these general principles can be applied here. The general UK public are being essentially told to look for certain things before even considering buying a product/service via a website.